# Dominion - Using Stash

Tags: dominion

How do you use this card strategically?  Since you don't know where any other cards are in your deck, how do you choose where to put this one?  Are there other cards this combines well with?

[image: Stash: 2 coin Treasure card. When you shuffle, you may put this anywhere in your deck.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally you would want to put it on top of your deck.  Getting a silver (essentially) is generally a pretty good move.

If you create a deck that draws a lot of cards you will be shuffling in the middle of your turn fairly often.  In that case, you definitely know whether you want to draw more treasures now or not.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes an attack card such as Thief or Spy can trigger a reshuffle.  In these cases, you would usually not want to put stash on top of your deck because it would get hit immediately.

Answer (score 3):

As far as combinations go, this card is good with anything that makes you reshuffle your deck  more frequently - Chancellor, obviously, but also Chapel or Trade Route or anything else that's commonly used to keep your deck size down.

Answer (score 3):

The [Dominion Strategy Blog](http://dominionstrategy.wordpress.com) has a nice post about leveraging [Chancellor and Stash](http://dominionstrategy.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/combo-of-the-day-17-chancellorstash/) together.

Answer (score 1):

It's fun w/ Wishing Well. Once you have 4 of them you can stack 'em together ensuring Province every deck-cycle. If there are other deck revealing/attack style stuff in play (Thief, Pirate Ship, Swindler, etc) you can put them near (but not directly on) the top of your deck so they aren't affected and you'll still draw them next turn.

Comment: Putting them below the top would not help much with Thief, Pirate Ship, etc. because generally you shuffle with intent to immediately draw 5 more cards for your next hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of Expands, it can be good to distribute them evenly in your deck so that you guarantee each hand has at least one 5-cost card you can turn into a Province. Granted, this is a pretty rare case.